# Pequeño problema con generador de contraseñas

Tags: c, cmd, compilar

soy más o menos nuevo en este mundillo de C y he estado haciendo este programa de generación de contraseñas:

Lo que va a hacer es mediante consola de comandos (cmd) nombraremos al archivo (en este caso se llama password) y seguido a esto especificaremos en consola lo que queremos que muestre: el número de caracteres que va a tener la contraseña poniendo (-1, -2, -3...) después si queremos que la contraseña sea solamente de letras minúsculas que lo especificaremos con: -n, si son mayúsculas con: -M, si es de números con: -d y luego si queremos utilizar varios de estos al mismo tiempo sería simplemente combinándolos, y si queremos que sea con todos los parámetros con -all.

He ido haciendo todo el código, el problema es que al llegar a compilarlo en cmd no me sale la contraseña definitiva generada, sino que me dice continuamente que la clave no es válida aún ingresando los parámetros que son.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto al código que llevo hecho:

**passwordgenerator.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

/* Cada uno de los parámetros necesarios para utilizar en la consola*/

#define CARACTERES_ESPECIALES "!@#$^&*?"
int mayusculas = 0;
int minusculas = 0;
int digitos = 0;
int especiales = 0;

char opcion[6];

if (strcmp(opcion, "M") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "n") == 0){

    minusculas = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "d") == 0){

    digitos = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "Mn") == 0 || strcmp(opcion, "nM") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
}
else if ((strcmp(opcion, "mdM")==0) || (strcmp(opcion, "mMd"))==0 || ((strcmp(opcion, "dmM")==0) || (strcmp(opcion, "Mmd"))==0)){

    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
    digitos = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "all") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
    digitos = 1;
    especiales = 1;
}
else{
    printf("Clave no v%clida.", 160);
    exit(-1);
}

/*Creamos el alfabeto de todos los parámetros para luego hacer la contraseña libremente*/

int tam_alfabeto = 1; // Para finalizar la cadena - depuración
if (mayusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
if (minusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'z' - 'a' + 1;
if (digitos)    tam_alfabeto += 10;
if (especiales) tam_alfabeto += strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES);

char * alfabeto = (char*)malloc(tam_alfabeto * sizeof(char));
int index = 0;

for (char c='A'; c<='Z' && mayusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='a'; c<='z' && minusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='0'; c<='9' && digitos; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (int i=0; i<strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES); i++)
    alfabeto[index++] = CARACTERES_ESPECIALES[i]; 

alfabeto[index] = 0; // Solo para fines de depuración

/*Generamos la contraseña*/

srand(time(NULL));

int clave_ok;
int longitud;
char*clave = (char*)malloc((longitud+1)*sizeof(char));
for( int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
{
    clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
}

clave[longitud] = 0; // Finalizamos la cadena

/*Hacemos una comprobación para que la contraseña tenga los parámetros que queremos*/

    do
    {
        for( int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
        }
 
        int hay_mayusculas = 0;
        int hay_minusculas = 0;
        int hay_digitos    = 0;
        int hay_especiales = 0;
 
        for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            hay_mayusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'A' && clave[i] <= 'Z');
            hay_minusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'a' && clave[i] <= 'z');
            hay_digitos    |= (clave[i] >= '0' && clave[i] <= '9');
            hay_especiales |= (strchr(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES, clave[i]) != NULL);
        }
 
        clave_ok = 1;
        if (mayusculas) clave_ok &= hay_mayusculas;
        if (minusculas) clave_ok &= hay_minusculas;
        if (digitos)    clave_ok &= hay_digitos;
        if (especiales) clave_ok &= hay_especiales;
 
        if (!clave_ok)
        {
            printf("Clave no v%clida: %s\n", 160, clave);
            exit(-1);
        }
    } while (!clave_ok);
 
    printf("Clave generada: %s\n", clave);
    free(clave);
}
```

Diría que el problema se encuentra al recoger los parámetros o en cuanto a la zona donde genero la contraseña, pero no lo se.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor? Muchas gracias.

**EDIT:**

Os comento un poco en lo que he ido avanzando en cuanto al código y el problema que me ha surgido, al final ya he hecho lo de utilizar `argc` y `argv` para pasar mis parámetros, pero tengo tres dudas en cuanto a este sistema...

(1) Realmente, para pasar los dígitos a la hora de indicar de cuanta longitud va a ser la contraseña como parámetro a la consola lo tengo que hacer indicando el número directamente en la consola. EJEMPLO: passwordgenerator -5 o -10 o -20, lo que quiera el usuario. Cuando se trata de un carácter fijo es fácil, ya que simplemente hay que indicarlo entre comillas ("-M"), tal y como lo tengo hecho en el código:

```
if (strcmp(argv[2], "-M") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
}
```

es decir que el "-d" para los dígitos que tengo en el programa realmente no me sirve para nada, ¿pero con un parámetro que va variando según lo que indique el usuario, en este caso números?

(2) Otra duda es en el `argv[]`, yo en mi código lo tengo puesto tal que así:

```
if(argc>1){

    if (strcmp(argv[2], "-M") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[3], "-n") == 0){

        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[4], "-d") == 0){ //El parámetro tiene que ser el número directamente, no "-d"

        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[5], "-Mn") == 0 || strcmp(argv[5], "-nM") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(argv[6], "-mdM")==0) || (strcmp(argv[6], "-mMd"))==0 || ((strcmp(argv[6], "-dmM")==0) || (strcmp(argv[6], "-Mmd"))==0)){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[7], "-all") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
        especiales = 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("Clave no v%clida. Debes utilizar los par%cmetros indicados:", 160, 160);
        printf("\n(-M, -n, -Mn, -mdM, -mMd, -dmM, -Mmd, -all)");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

La duda reside en qué valor le tengo que asignar a cada `argv[]`, ya que existe la posibilidad de que al ingresar mayúsculas y minúsculas, el usuario ingrese -Mn y esto se encontraría en el `argv[2]`, no en el argv[5] que lo tengo puesto, el problema es que si el usuario pide que sean solamente mayúsculas (-M), entonces el programa si que estaría bien ya que está en el `argv[2]`

(3) Además, en cuanto al `argv[]` en cada uno de los parámetros, hay otro problema, y es que cuando utilizamos el operador de disyunción `||` para que el usuario pueda utilizar tanto un parámetro como otro, como ocurre por ejemplo cuando quiere que se contraseña tenga mayúsculas y minúsculas:

```
else if (strcmp(argv[5], "-Mn") == 0 || strcmp(argv[5], "-nM") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
}
```

Tengo puesto como que están almacenados en el mismo argv[5] pero no tengo del todo claro si es correcto así como lo he hecho.

Ahora mismo tal y como tengo hecho el programa compila bien, pero a la hora de ingresar los parámetros (que es el núcleo del problema) se vuelve un poco loco e ingresa claves que no deberían ser. Además, el problema que tenía con lo de longitud que me había dicho @Pablochaches ya en principio lo he solucionado simplemente sustituyendolo por `argc`. Siento haberme explicado un poco mal, pero se me hace complejo. Muchas gracias y espero que me podáis ayudar.

El código completo del programa es este por si lo queréis ver:

**passwordgenerator.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CARACTERES_ESPECIALES "!@#$^&*?"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

/* Cada uno de los parámetros necesarios para utilizar en la consola*/

int mayusculas = 0;
int minusculas = 0;
int digitos = 0;
int especiales = 0;

if(argc>1){

    if (strcmp(argv[2], "-M") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[3], "-n") == 0){

        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[4], "-d") == 0){ //El parámetro tiene que ser el número directamente, no "-d"

        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[5], "-Mn") == 0 || strcmp(argv[5], "-nM") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(argv[6], "-mdM")==0) || (strcmp(argv[6], "-mMd"))==0 || ((strcmp(argv[6], "-dmM")==0) || (strcmp(argv[6], "-Mmd"))==0)){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[7], "-all") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
        especiales = 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("Clave no v%clida. Debes utilizar los par%cmetros indicados:", 160, 160);
        printf("\n(-M, -n, -d, -Mn, -mdM, -mMd, -dmM, -Mmd, -all)");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
/*Creamos el alfabeto de todos los parámetros para luego hacer la contraseña libremente*/

int tam_alfabeto = 1; // Para finalizar la cadena - depuración
if (mayusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
if (minusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'z' - 'a' + 1;
if (digitos)    tam_alfabeto += 10;
if (especiales) tam_alfabeto += strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES);

char * alfabeto = (char*)malloc(tam_alfabeto * sizeof(char));
int index = 0;

for (char c='A'; c<='Z' && mayusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='a'; c<='z' && minusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='0'; c<='9' && digitos; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (int i=0; i<strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES); i++)
    alfabeto[index++] = CARACTERES_ESPECIALES[i]; 

alfabeto[index] = 0; // Solo para fines de depuración

/*Generamos la contraseña*/

srand(time(NULL));

int clave_ok;
char*clave = (char*)malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(char));
for( int i=0; i<argc; i++){

    clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
}

clave[argc] = 0; // Finalizamos la cadena

/*Hacemos una comprobación para que la contraseña tenga los parámetros que queremos*/

    do{
    
        for( int i=0; i<argc; i++){
        
            clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
        }
 
        int hay_mayusculas = 0;
        int hay_minusculas = 0;
        int hay_digitos    = 0;
        int hay_especiales = 0;
 
        for (int i=0; i<argc; i++){
        
            hay_mayusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'A' && clave[i] <= 'Z');
            hay_minusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'a' && clave[i] <= 'z');
            hay_digitos    |= (clave[i] >= '0' && clave[i] <= '9');
            hay_especiales |= (strchr(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES, clave[i]) != NULL);
        }
 
        clave_ok = 1;
        if (mayusculas) clave_ok &= hay_mayusculas;
        if (minusculas) clave_ok &= hay_minusculas;
        if (digitos)    clave_ok &= hay_digitos;
        if (especiales) clave_ok &= hay_especiales;
 
        if (!clave_ok){
        
            printf("Clave no v%clida: %s\n", 160, clave);
            exit(-1);
        }
    } while (!clave_ok);
 
    printf("Clave generada: %s\n", clave);
    free(clave);
}
```

Comment: Defines `opcion` y sin darle ningún valor, te pones a comparar su contenido. Dónde dices que recoges los parámetros?

Comment: Realmente los parámetros no los recoge, simplemente que cuando la persona ponga en consola -M o -n o lo que sea, el programa sabe que son mayúsculas, minúsculas... Y en cuanto a lo de opcion, ¿se supone que tendría que darle algún valor? Pensaba que poniendo char opcion y el numero de opciones (parametros para ingresar en consola) me serviría. Perdona si no te entiendo o algo, pero me cuesta todavía.

Comment: Si te refieres a que puedan llamar a tu programa pasándole parámetros en la llamada, del tipo: _tu_programa -M -r -loquesea_; esos parámetros los recibes en la función `main` en `argc` (ahí te dice cuantos hay contando con el nombre de tu programa, en mi ejemplo serían 4) y en `argv`, como un array de punteros a cadena con cada parámetro. Te toca a ti extraer de ahí esos parámetros e interpretarlos para cambiar el comportamiento de tu programa en función de ellos. Tienes mil ejemplos en internet.

Comment: Lo mismo que haces con opcion lo estas haciendo con longitud, tomas una variable sin inicializar y la pasas directo a malloc. Las variables sin inicializar pueden tener contenido basura, eso significa que a saber que cantidad de memoria le vas a pedir a malloc en ese caso.

Comment: @SuperG280 Si, tengo claro que lo tengo que hacer dentro de la función main pero por ejemplo, ¿cómo harías tu para que en argc les pases esos 4 parámetros (de tu ejemplo)? Igual me vendría bien que me pasarais algún ejemplo parecido al mio, porque no me aclaro muy bien con lo de "inicializarlas". Y si, lo mismo me ha pasado con longitud porque me creo que simplemente declarando longitud mediante int ya puedo trabajar con ella.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que en cada if que tengo de los parámetros tenga que poner dentro de este un argv[]?

Comment: Cuando defines una variable, puedes usarla, pero si no le das un valor inicial, tomará un valor aleatorio y cuando vayas a usarla, puede pasar cualquier cosa. Por eso, le debes dar un valor inicial antes de empezar a consultar su valor. Por ejemplo a cero: `int variable = 0;`. Ahora `variable` vale cero y lo seguirá valiendo hasta que lo vuelvas a cambiar. Cuando llamas a tu programa con parámetros, ya te llegan posicionados en `argc` y `argv` al entrar en la función `main`. Solo tienes que utilizar las variables `argc` y `argv` en tu función `main`. Busca ejemplos que hay a miles en google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es absurdo:

```
if(argc>1){

    if (strcmp(argv[2], "-M") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[3], "-n") == 0){

        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[4], "-d") == 0){ //El parámetro tiene que ser el número directamente, no "-d"

        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[5], "-Mn") == 0 || strcmp(argv[5], "-nM") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(argv[6], "-mdM")==0) || (strcmp(argv[6], "-mMd"))==0 || ((strcmp(argv[6], "-dmM")==0) || (strcmp(argv[6], "-Mmd"))==0)){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[7], "-all") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
        especiales = 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("Clave no v%clida. Debes utilizar los par%cmetros indicados:", 160, 160);
        printf("\n(-M, -n, -Mn, -mdM, -mMd, -dmM, -Mmd, -all)");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Porque generas la siguiente condición:

> Los parámetros serán incorrectos si no se cumplen ninguna de estas condiciones
>
> - El tercer parámetro no es -M
> - El cuarto parámetro no es -n
> - El quinto parámetro no es -d
> - El sexto parámetro no es -Mn o -nM
>   ...

(Nota: empiezo en el tercero porque recordemos que en C los índices empiezan en 0, luego el índice 2 se corresponde con el tercer elemento.)

Cuando tu realmente lo que quieres es algo como lo siguiente:

> Los parámetros serán incorrectos si alguno de ellos no es
>
> - -M
> - -n
> - -d
> - Cualquier combinación lineal de los anteriores
> - -all

Es decir, deberías iterar por todos los parámetros y evaluarlos uno a uno

```
for( int i=1; i<argc; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-M") == 0)
    {
        mayusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-n") == 0)
    {
        minusculas = 1;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Nota que empezamos validando `argv[1]`. Esto se debe a que `argv[0]` **siempre** será el nombre de la aplicación

Comment: ¿Y si uno de los parámetros es un número que el usuario quiera? Por ejemplo, si se quiere hacer una contraseña de 10 o 20 caracteres o los que sean. Sería como utilizar ese número que me ha dado para yo hacer luego la longitud de la contraseña.

Comment: tienes un método `isdigit` que recibe un `char` y te indica si el caracter se corresponde a un dígito numérico o no. En el `else` final añades un bucle para comprobar si el parámetro es un número  o no. Si lo es, cargas el tamaño de la clave, si no lo es, muestras un mensaje de error. Otra posibilidad es que el primer parámetro sea obligatoriamente la longitud. En ese caso valida ese parámetro en primer lugar y luego pones el for que valida el resto pero haciendo que empiece en `i=2`

Comment: En este caso se trata de la segunda opción, el primer parámetro tiene que ser siempre el de la longitud, pero, ¿Cómo valido ese parámetro?
`if (isdigit (*argv[1])){
//???
        
}`

Comment: @Minibiru No es mi intención hacerte todo el ejercicio. Si te resuelvo todo el problema no vas a aprender nada

Comment: Vale, no pasa nada ya me has ayudado bastante, gracias.